# Git: unable to create temporary object directory - altough permissions of the folder are set to everyone?

Tags: git

Answers to similar questions pointed to no disk space and permission problems. Disk space is enough and the permission of the *repository*-folder are set to everyone has full access. We access the network via VPN with non-domain users. It's a freshly installed windows server with default installation git and a "new" repository: new init with old source folder added and commited. It's pullable, but not pushable.

The error (with *placeholders*):

```
error: remote unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory
To file:////*server*/*repository*/.git/
! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
```

The **repository** folder and each subfolder has the everyone full access permission.

Do I need to add the git users to a `config`? Are there any other folders that need permissions changed besides the repo folders?

Comment: This was the solution. The shared folder permission was on read only, thanks a lot

Comment: I've posted it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows shared folders also have their own permissions, which are applied on top of filesystem permissions. You might want to check those.